# AWS CloudFormation deployment is failing which is using resources imported from another template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am deploying my infrastructure to AWS using the CloudFormation templates. I have two templates core.yaml and resources.yaml. The core.yaml file is using the resources from the core.yaml importing them into the template. The resources.yaml file is exporting the resources. But when I deployed my core.yaml file, it is failing. Below is my code.

resources.yaml

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: "Permanent resources to be imported"
Parameters:
  SSHLocation:
    Description: The IP address range that can be used to SSH to the EC2 instances
    Type: String
    MinLength: '9'
    MaxLength: '18'
    Default: 0.0.0.0/0
    AllowedPattern: "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})"
    ConstraintDescription: Must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x
  DBInstanceIdentifier:
    Type: String
    Default: 'patheindbidentifier'
  DBName:
    Type: String
    Default: 'patheindb'
  DBUsername:
    Type: String
    Default: 'patheindbadmin'
  DBClass:
    Type: String
    Default: 'db.t2.micro'
  DBAllocatedStorage:
    Type: String
    Default: '5'
  DBPassword:
    Type: String

Resources:
  StorageBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      BucketName: pathein-directory-storage
      AccessControl: PublicRead

  WebServerSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Security Group for EC2 instances
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '80'
          ToPort: '80'
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '22'
          ToPort: '22'
          CidrIp:
            Ref: SSHLocation

  DBSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Database security group
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '3306'
          ToPort: '3306'
          SourceSecurityGroupId: !GetAtt WebServerSecurityGroup.GroupId

  WebDatabase:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      DBInstanceIdentifier: !Ref DBInstanceIdentifier
      DBName: !Ref DBName
      DBInstanceClass: !Ref DBClass
      AllocatedStorage: !Ref DBAllocatedStorage
      Engine: MySQL
      MasterUsername: !Ref DBUsername
      MasterUserPassword: !Ref DBPassword
      VPCSecurityGroups:
        - !GetAtt DBSecurityGroup.GroupId

Outputs:
  StorageBucket:
    Description: "S3 storage bucket"
    Value: !Ref StorageBucket
    Export:
      Name: PatheinStorageBucket
  WebServerSecurityGroup:
    Description: "Web server security group"
    Value: !GetAtt WebServerSecurityGroup.GroupId
    Export:
      Name: PatheinWebServerSecurityGroup
  DBSecurityGroup:
    Description: "Database security group"
    Value: !Ref DBSecurityGroup
    Export:
      Name: PatheinDBSecurityGroup
  WebDatabase:
    Description: "Web database"
    Value: !Ref WebDatabase
    Export:
      Name: PatheinWebDatabases
  SSHLocation:
    Description: "SSH Location"
    Value: !Ref SSHLocation
    Export:
      Name: PatheinSSHLocation
  DatabaseHost:
    Description: "Database host"
    Value: !GetAtt WebDatabase.Endpoint.Address
  DatabasePort:
    Description: "Database port"
    Value: !GetAtt WebDatabase.Endpoint.Port
```

As you can see in the template, I am exporting all the resources. I could successfully deploy the resources.yaml into the AWS.

This is my core.yaml file.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: "Pathein Directory web application deployment template."
Parameters:
  KeyName:
    Default: 'PatheinDirectory'
    Type: String
  InstanceType:
    Default: 't2.micro'
    Type: String

Mappings:
  Region2Principal:
    us-east-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    us-west-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    us-west-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-west-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-west-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-west-3:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-southeast-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-northeast-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-northeast-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-northeast-3:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-southeast-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-south-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    us-east-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ca-central-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    sa-east-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    cn-north-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com.cn
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com.cn
    cn-northwest-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com.cn
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com.cn
    eu-central-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-north-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com

  Beanstalk2Route53HostedZoneId:
    us-east-1:
      HostedZoneId: Z3DZXE0Q79N41H
    us-west-1:
      HostedZoneId: Z1M58G0W56PQJA
    us-west-2:
      HostedZoneId: Z33MTJ483KN6FU
    eu-west-1:
      HostedZoneId: Z3NF1Z3NOM5OY2
    ap-northeast-1:
      HostedZoneId: Z2YN17T5R711GT
    ap-southeast-1:
      HostedZoneId: Z1WI8VXHPB1R38
    sa-east-1:
      HostedZoneId: Z2ES78Y61JGQKS

Resources:
  WebServerRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - Fn::FindInMap:
                    - Region2Principal
                    - Ref: AWS::Region
                    - EC2Principal
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: /

  WebServerRolePolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: WebServerRole
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            NotAction: iam:*
            Resource: '*'
      Roles:
        - Ref: WebServerRole

  WebServerInstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: /
      Roles:
        - Ref: WebServerRole

  Application:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: PatheinDirectoryApplication
      Description: AWS Elastic Beanstalk Pathein Directory Laravel application

  ApplicationVersion:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion
    Properties:
      Description: Version 1.0
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: Application
      SourceBundle:
        S3Bucket:
          Fn::Join:
            - '-'
            - - elasticbeanstalk-samples
              - Ref: AWS::Region
        S3Key: php-sample.zip

  ApplicationConfigurationTemplate:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate
    Properties:
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: Application
      Description: SSH access to Pathein Directory Laravel application
      SolutionStackName: 64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.1.0 running PHP 7.3
      OptionSettings:
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
          OptionName: EC2KeyName
          Value:
            Ref: KeyName
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
          OptionName: IamInstanceProfile
          Value:
            Ref: WebServerInstanceProfile
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
          OptionName: SecurityGroups
          Value:
            !ImportValue PatheinWebServerSecurityGroup

  Environment:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment
    Properties:
      Description: AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment running Pathein Directory Laravel application
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: Application
      EnvironmentName: PatheinDirectory
      TemplateName:
        Ref: ApplicationConfigurationTemplate
      VersionLabel:
        Ref: ApplicationVersion
      OptionSettings:
        - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini
          OptionName: document_root
          Value: /public

  ElasticCacheSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Enable TCP connection on port 6379
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '11211'
          ToPort: '11211'
          SourceSecurityGroupId: !ImportValue PatheinWebServerSecurityGroup

  ElasticCacheCluster:
    Type: AWS::ElastiCache::CacheCluster
    Properties:
      AZMode: cross-az
      CacheNodeType: cache.t2.small
      Engine: memcached
      NumCacheNodes: '2'
      VpcSecurityGroupIds:
        - !GetAtt ElasticCacheSecurityGroup.GroupId
      PreferredAvailabilityZones:
        - !Select
          - 0
          - Fn::GetAZs: !Ref AWS::Region
        - !Select
          - 1
          - Fn::GetAZs: !Ref AWS::Region
```

It is failing when I deployed the core.yaml file. The following is the error I got in the log.

```
{
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/patheindirectory/5da3be20-ef6c-11ea-8dc6-0275bf88180c",
            "EventId": "b7aa01e0-ef6c-11ea-b8c0-06e621efe3ec",
            "StackName": "patheindirectory",
            "LogicalResourceId": "patheindirectory",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:733553390213:stack/patheindirectory/5da3be20-ef6c-11ea-8dc6-0275bf88180c",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
            "Timestamp": "2020-09-05T11:41:20.498000+00:00",
            "ResourceStatus": "ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS",
            "ResourceStatusReason": "The following resource(s) failed to create: [ElasticCacheCluster, ApplicationConfigurationTemplate]. . Rollback requested by user."
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have interesting case showing inconsistencies in CloudFormation. In some cases Security Group (SG) ID (for `ElasticCacheCluster`) is required, in other cases SG Name (for `ApplicationConfigurationTemplate`) is needed. Thus in your case you need to export both from `resources.yaml` and respectively import them in `core.yaml`. Also `SolutionStackName` needed to be updated.

The **fixed templates** are below. I verified that they **work and deploy** in `us-east-1` region. I only verified their deployment, not functionality of the resulting resources.

**resources.yaml**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: "Permanent resources to be imported"
Parameters:
  SSHLocation:
    Description: The IP address range that can be used to SSH to the EC2 instances
    Type: String
    MinLength: '9'
    MaxLength: '18'
    Default: 0.0.0.0/0
    AllowedPattern: "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})"
    ConstraintDescription: Must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x
  DBInstanceIdentifier:
    Type: String
    Default: 'patheindbidentifier'
  DBName:
    Type: String
    Default: 'patheindb'
  DBUsername:
    Type: String
    Default: 'patheindbadmin'
  DBClass:
    Type: String
    Default: 'db.t2.micro'
  DBAllocatedStorage:
    Type: String
    Default: '5'
  DBPassword:
    Type: String

Resources:
  StorageBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      BucketName: pathein-directory-storage-32112
      AccessControl: PublicRead

  WebServerSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Security Group for EC2 instances
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '80'
          ToPort: '80'
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '22'
          ToPort: '22'
          CidrIp:
            Ref: SSHLocation

  DBSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Database security group
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '3306'
          ToPort: '3306'
          SourceSecurityGroupId: !GetAtt WebServerSecurityGroup.GroupId

  WebDatabase:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      DBInstanceIdentifier: !Ref DBInstanceIdentifier
      DBName: !Ref DBName
      DBInstanceClass: !Ref DBClass
      AllocatedStorage: !Ref DBAllocatedStorage
      Engine: MySQL
      MasterUsername: !Ref DBUsername
      MasterUserPassword: !Ref DBPassword
      VPCSecurityGroups:
        - !GetAtt DBSecurityGroup.GroupId

Outputs:
  StorageBucket:
    Description: "S3 storage bucket"
    Value: !Ref StorageBucket
    Export:
      Name: PatheinStorageBucket
  WebServerSecurityGroupName:
    Description: "Web server security group"
    Value: !Ref WebServerSecurityGroup
    Export:
      Name: PatheinWebServerSecurityGroupName
  WebServerSecurityGroupId:
    Description: "Web server security group"
    Value: !GetAtt WebServerSecurityGroup.GroupId
    Export:
      Name: PatheinWebServerSecurityGroupId      
  DBSecurityGroup:
    Description: "Database security group"
    Value: !Ref DBSecurityGroup
    Export:
      Name: PatheinDBSecurityGroup
  WebDatabase:
    Description: "Web database"
    Value: !Ref WebDatabase
    Export:
      Name: PatheinWebDatabases
  SSHLocation:
    Description: "SSH Location"
    Value: !Ref SSHLocation
    Export:
      Name: PatheinSSHLocation
  DatabaseHost:
    Description: "Database host"
    Value: !GetAtt WebDatabase.Endpoint.Address
  DatabasePort:
    Description: "Database port"
    Value: !GetAtt WebDatabase.Endpoint.Port
```

**core.yaml**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: "Pathein Directory web application deployment template."
Parameters:
  KeyName:
    Default: 'PatheinDirectory'
    Type: String
  InstanceType:
    Default: 't2.micro'
    Type: String

Mappings:
  Region2Principal:
    us-east-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    us-west-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    us-west-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-west-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-west-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-west-3:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-southeast-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-northeast-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-northeast-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-northeast-3:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-southeast-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ap-south-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    us-east-2:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    ca-central-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    sa-east-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    cn-north-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com.cn
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com.cn
    cn-northwest-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com.cn
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com.cn
    eu-central-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com
    eu-north-1:
      EC2Principal: ec2.amazonaws.com
      OpsWorksPrincipal: opsworks.amazonaws.com

  Beanstalk2Route53HostedZoneId:
    us-east-1:
      HostedZoneId: Z3DZXE0Q79N41H
    us-west-1:
      HostedZoneId: Z1M58G0W56PQJA
    us-west-2:
      HostedZoneId: Z33MTJ483KN6FU
    eu-west-1:
      HostedZoneId: Z3NF1Z3NOM5OY2
    ap-northeast-1:
      HostedZoneId: Z2YN17T5R711GT
    ap-southeast-1:
      HostedZoneId: Z1WI8VXHPB1R38
    sa-east-1:
      HostedZoneId: Z2ES78Y61JGQKS

Resources:
  WebServerRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - Fn::FindInMap:
                    - Region2Principal
                    - Ref: AWS::Region
                    - EC2Principal
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: /

  WebServerRolePolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: WebServerRole
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            NotAction: iam:*
            Resource: '*'
      Roles:
        - Ref: WebServerRole

  WebServerInstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: /
      Roles:
        - Ref: WebServerRole

  Application:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: PatheinDirectoryApplication
      Description: AWS Elastic Beanstalk Pathein Directory Laravel application

  ApplicationVersion:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion
    Properties:
      Description: Version 1.0
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: Application
      SourceBundle:
        S3Bucket:
          Fn::Join:
            - '-'
            - - elasticbeanstalk-samples
              - Ref: AWS::Region
        S3Key: php-sample.zip

  ApplicationConfigurationTemplate:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate
    Properties:
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: Application
      Description: SSH access to Pathein Directory Laravel application
      SolutionStackName: 64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.1.1 running PHP 7.3
      OptionSettings:
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
          OptionName: EC2KeyName
          Value:
            Ref: KeyName
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
          OptionName: IamInstanceProfile
          Value:
            Ref: WebServerInstanceProfile
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
          OptionName: SecurityGroups
          Value:
            !ImportValue PatheinWebServerSecurityGroupName

  Environment:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment
    Properties:
      Description: AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment running Pathein Directory Laravel application
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: Application
      EnvironmentName: PatheinDirectory
      TemplateName:
        Ref: ApplicationConfigurationTemplate
      VersionLabel:
        Ref: ApplicationVersion
      OptionSettings:
        - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini
          OptionName: document_root
          Value: /public

  ElasticCacheSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Enable TCP connection on port 6379
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '11211'
          ToPort: '11211'
          SourceSecurityGroupId: !ImportValue PatheinWebServerSecurityGroupId

  ElasticCacheCluster:
    Type: AWS::ElastiCache::CacheCluster
    Properties:
      AZMode: cross-az
      CacheNodeType: cache.t2.small
      Engine: memcached
      NumCacheNodes: '2'
      VpcSecurityGroupIds:
        - !GetAtt ElasticCacheSecurityGroup.GroupId
      PreferredAvailabilityZones:
        - !Select
          - 0
          - Fn::GetAZs: !Ref AWS::Region
        - !Select
          - 1
          - Fn::GetAZs: !Ref AWS::Region
```

Comment: @WaiYanHein No problem. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you can find more detailed error messages when you take a look at the stack events in the CloudFormation console. In this case I got 2 errors for the `ApplicationConfigurationTemplate` resource:

1 `No Solution Stack named '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.1.0 running PHP 7.3' found`:
The issue is that the version you specified was only [valid until September 2, 2020](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platform-history-php.html). You can check the current platform versions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-supported.html#platforms-supported.PHP). So I had to update the SolutionStackName attribute: `SolutionStackName: 64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.1.1 running PHP 7.3`

2 `Configuration validation exception: Invalid option value: 'sg-xxx' (Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration', OptionName: 'SecurityGroups'): The security group 'sg-xxx' does not exist`: This is related to the following code piece:

```
    - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
      OptionName: SecurityGroups
      Value:
        !ImportValue PatheinWebServerSecurityGroup
```

The issue is that in this case not the logical ID (Security Group ID), but the physical ID (Security Group Name) of the Security Group is required. This means you have to add another export to the resources.yaml template like this:

```
  WebServerSecurityGroupName:
    Description: "Web server security group name"
    Value: !Ref WebServerSecurityGroup
    Export:
      Name: PatheinWebServerSecurityGroupName
```

Then you can import it to core.yaml:

```
- Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
  OptionName: SecurityGroups
  Value:
    !ImportValue PatheinWebServerSecurityGroupName
```

Note that you still need to export the logical ID as it's used by `ElasticCacheSecurityGroup`.

Comment: Hi, I have fixed the PHP image issue. But it is still complaining that the security group does not exist. I checked in the console and it exists. How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you added a new export to resources.yaml for the physical resource ID as I described in 2.? I edited my answer to include code samples for that.